# Puppeteer : Programmatically save Chrome performance timeline for long running sessions

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, selenium-chromedriver, puppeteer

I am trying to record timeline trace of a web page using puppeteer tracing API.

```
await page.tracing.start({ path: 'trace.json'});
//do stuff on web page for x seconds
await page.tracing.stop();
```

If I run trace for 1 minutes, generated trace.json file size is more than 200 MB. When I load the file in performance tab of chrome, I see lot of details missing. Usually Chrome timeline has details like Network, Frame, Interactions, Timing, Main etc. Following is a screenshot of timeline trace generated from my trace.json[image: Figure 1]

It just has Browser, Renderer and GPU Process information but not Network, frame, Main etc.

If I run trace for 10 seconds, trace.json file size is around 25 mb and it renders properly in the timeline panel with all the details like Network, Frame, Interactions, Timing, Main etc. [image]

Why is  visual representation of timeline trace in above 2 scenarios different ?

I have to do long running tests on web page which will run for 10-15 minutes. How Can I record timeline trace of web page in such scenarios so that I get trace like the one in Figure 2 with all the details like network calls etc.

Should I collect trace every 10-15 seconds periodically by repeatedly invoking tracing.start  for the entire duration of test for 15 minutes. Is there any upper limit on the size of trace generated or tracing duration ?
Is there any better alternative to save timeline of chrome ?